# Is it possible to have multiple control button.Tag

Tags: c#, winforms

This app prompts you to open a folder. The app then looks at all the files in the folder and generates a button for each (.wav) file. My intention was then to play the (.wav) file when the button is pressed.

As it is I am dynamically creating the buttons. I use the `button.Tag` to send the button number however I wish to send another object that holds the full path to the wav file. I have pseudo added it however, I know you can not add two `button.Tag` like I have done. So my question is how do I implement this.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public SoundPlayer Sound1;
    public static int btnCount = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetFolderPath();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void addDynamicButton(string folder, string fileName)
    {
        btnCount++;
        string soundfilepath = folder + "\\" + fileName + ".wav";

        Button button = new Button();
        button.Location = new Point(20, 30 * btnCount + 10);
        button.Size = new Size(300, 23);

        button.Text = fileName;
        button.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        button.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

        button.Click += new EventHandler(btnDynClickEvent);
        button.Tag = btnCount;
        button.Tag = soundfilepath;
        this.Controls.Add(button);

    }

    void btnDynClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {

            switch ((int)button.Tag)
            {
                case 1:
                    Sound1 = new SoundPlayer((string)button.Tag);
                Sound1.Play();
                break;

            }
        }
    }

    public void SetFolderPath()
    {

        FolderBrowserDialog folder = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        folder.Description = "Select the sound file Folder";

        if (textBox1.Text.Length > 2)
        {
            folder.SelectedPath = textBox1.Text;
        }

        else
        {
            folder.SelectedPath = @"C:\";
        }

        if (folder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = folder.SelectedPath;

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder.SelectedPath, "*.wav", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            int count = files.Length;

            richTextBox1.Text = count.ToString() + " Files Found";

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
                addDynamicButton(folder.SelectedPath, fileName);
            }
        }
    }


    private void btnOpenFolder(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetFolderPath();
    }


}
```

Comment: Declare a class **ExtraButtonInfo** that holds **all** the extra information needed for each button, and assign instances of  **ExtraButtonInfo** to each Button's Tag property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend a specialized object to store in the `Tag` property:

```
class WaveDetailTag {

    public FileInfo WaveFile {get; set;}
    public int ButtonId {get; set;}

}
```

Implementation:

```
// ...
button.Tag = new WaveDetailTag() { 
    WaveFile = new FileInfo(soundfilepath), 
    ButtonId = btnCount 
};
// ...
```

**Update**
Using in `switch-case`:

```
    Button button = sender as Button;
    if (button != null)
    {
        var waveDetail = (WaveDetailTag)button.Tag;
        switch (waveDetail.ButtonId)
        {
            case 1:
                Sound1 = new SoundPlayer(waveDetail.WaveFile.FullName);
                Sound1.Play();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @IAbstract How would i go about using it in the switch case?

Answer (score 3):

you should set you tag like

```
button.Tag= new {Count = btnCount, FileName=soundFfilepath);//anonymouse type
```

the when you want to retrieve your values you can use **dynamic**

```
int count=((dynamic)button.Tag).Count;
string filename=((dynamic)button.Tag).FileName;
```

or

```
int count=(int) button.Tag.GetType().GetProperty("Count").GetValue(obj, null);
string filename= button.Tag.GetType().GetProperty("FileName").GetValue(obj, null).ToString();
```

---

you can also create a new method for the second solution

```
object GetValueByProperty(object obj,string propName)
{
 return   obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

to call simply use

```
int count=(int) GetValueByProperty(button.Tag,"Count");
string filename=GetValueByProperty(button.Tag,"FileName");.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks 4 your help.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple tags isn't REALLY possible, but you can use a `List` (`List<object>` or `List<MyType>`) or an array as the `Tag`.

You can also create your own class to contain all wanted information, which would be preferable:

```
class MyTagInfo
{
    public int Num;
    public string Text;
    public bool SomeMoreInfo;
}
```

And usage:

```
myControl.Tag = new MyTagInfo { Num = 0, Text = "Hello World!" };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store a List into the Tag property, which allows you to store multiple objects in it.

```
button.Tag = new List<object>();
(List<object> button.Tag).Add(btnCount);
(List<object> button.Tag).Add(soundfilepath);
```

Comment: Unknown method or extension to `Tag` of type `object` named `Add`, or something like that. You should cast the `Tag` to a `List<object>` in order to use it as a list.

Comment: Tag is an `Object` and must be cast before adding anything

Comment: IMO, a `List<object>` (or any list) is a really bad idea. The assumption that `[0]` is an `int` and `[1]` is a `string` leaves a lot of room for mistakes - not to mention the casting of items from `object`.

Comment: Agreed that a specific class is more neat in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom class and store it in the `Tag` property, something like:

```
public class WaveButton
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string WaveFilePath { get; set; }
}

.....


button.Tag = new WaveButton() { Number = n, WaveFilePath = path }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its too Late but i come up with an easy way to do that. 
just join strings like `string join = String.join(","firstString,secondString);
button.Tag = join;`
and before using it just split it into two strings like this

```
string[] split = join.Split(',');
        string title = split[1];
        string link = split[0];
```

and use string title and string link as you like. (Y) 
I don't know if it is a good practice or not but i am using it and it work perfect.

> I am new to c#.